# How do I create a list of class instances that have multiple arguments?

Tags: python

I created a class of objects with seven arguments. I want to create a list of the instances.

This is what the class looks like:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, position, age, handedness, number, team)
```

As of now, I have 12 instances of the class (I want to make it longer once I can make this functional). E.g.:

```
dw = ("David Wright", "3B", 32, "R", 5, "Mets")
```

This is my attempt to create the list:

```
player_list = []
for i in range(12):
    player_list.append(Player())
```

I am getting an error that I have only supplied one argument (which I realize), but the Class takes 7. How can I fix this?

Comment: you should pass in the parameters: `Player(*dw)`. and i can't understand ` I have 12 instances of the class`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to put your arguments in to a list of tuples or dictionaries. For example:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, position, age, handedness, number, team):
        self.name = name
        self.position = position
        self.age = age
        self.handedness = handedness
        self.number = number
        self.team = team


player_data = [("David Wright", "3B", 32, "R", 5, "Mets"),
               ('Another Person', '2e', 43, "S", 4, "Teams!")]
players = [Player(*player) for player in player_data]
for player in players:
    print(player.number)
```

This takes each [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html) from the list `player_date` and uses `*` to do something called unrolling/unpacking.

Basically, it takes the tuple and passes each element of the tuple to the function/constructor (`Player` in this case) in order.

You can also do this with a dictionary with `**`, this allows you to pass arguments to functions/constructors with keyword arguments with the key of the dictionary as the keyword, and the value as the data.

Comment: Thanks very much! Will this make me create the instances of the class outside this dictionary or will they be created in the list / dictionary? Ideally i'd like to only have to input this data once so that the list would just autoupdate

Comment: @Ethan This doesn't use a dictionary, and I'm not sure what you mean by autoupdate?

Comment: I meant to say list / dictionary. What I'd like to do is have a list that contains all the instances in the class.

Comment: (continuing) so that I can

Comment: @Ethan Yeah, that's what `players` is. You can iterate over that and it will have every instance of `Player` in it.

Comment: (1) iterate through it; (2) change the list so that i am not changing the actual data in the class

Comment: Great, thank you! So do I need to create the instances outside the list player_data? when I try to do that alone i'm getting this error message:

   player_list = [Player(*player) for player in player_data]
TypeError: type object argument after * must be a sequence, not Player

Comment: @Ethan I just gave a more complete example in my post. It works fine on my machine.

Comment: ahhh I think I figured out why mine isn't working. I'm running 2.7.10! any suggestions ? :-/

Comment: Not without knowing why it isn't working? Is it just that its `print player.number` instead of `print(player.number)`? And this works in 2.7. I just tested.

Comment: Thanks, Morgan. I can't figure out why it's wrong but I'm just going to start my code from scratch because yours seems to be working!

Comment: @Ethan No problem, glad I could help. If you wouldn't mind accepting this answer (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer), that would be great. That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives me credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: Done! This worked. Just one thing, I should be able to manipulate this new list without changing any of the class data, right?

Comment: @Ethan I mean, as long as you don't change any of the classes data, eg, `player.number = 20`, none of the class data will change.